# string manipulation one row at time in PowerShell

Tags: powershell-3.0

I have a large text that needs to be worked on, one row at a time. The way I do now, is send the data to a text file (as in the below code) and import back into a variable, which allows me to use the foreach construct. I'm sure there's a better way than this. I appreciate any help.

```
$rawData = '
This is a multiline text1 
This is a multiline text2
This is a multiline text3 
This is a multiline text4 
'

$rawData | Out-File c:\temp.txt -Force  
$DataFromFile = Get-Content c:\temp.txt 

foreach ($i in $DataFromFile) {
     $i 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split it directly:

```ps
foreach ($row in $rawData -split '\r?\n') {
    $row
}
```

Or extract manually to avoid creating a temporary array:

```ps
$pos = 0
do {
    # exract the next line
    $i = $rawData.indexOfAny("`r`n", $pos)
    if ($i -eq -1) { $i = $rawData.length }
    $row = $rawData.substring($pos, $i - $pos)
    while ($rawData[$i+1] -match "[\r\n]") { $i++ }
    $pos = $i + 1

    #process the line    
    $row
} until ($pos -ge $rawData.length)
```

Also use literal quotes to avoid empty lines in the string:

```ps
$rawData = @'
This is a multiline text1 
This is a multiline text2
This is a multiline text3 
This is a multiline text4
'@
```